# Init local stream failed

Tags: agora.io

I am trying `Live Broadcast` using `AgoraRTC`.

```
AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: 'live'});
Client.init(appId, function(){...});
Client.setClientRole("host");
Client.join(null, "channelName", null, function(uid){...});
AgoraRTC.createStream({
    streamID: uid, 
    video: true, 
    audio: true, 
    screen: false
});
```

The above has been successful.
However, an error always occurs in the next `Stream.init()`.
And the contents of the error are as follows.

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "info": "The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.",
    "msg": "NotAllowedError"
}
```

Is something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "However, an error always occurs in the next Stream.init(). And the contents of the error are as follows."?  Are you attempting to init two streams from the same device?

Comment: It does not mean to initialize two streams. Calling Stream.init() always results in an error.